# Wrong Date calculation by date on Ubuntu 16, 20

Tags: ubuntu, date

The weirdest thing happens to date calculation because of what you see below; notice that adding one month to Oct 31st takes it to December! This can't be? I have the same issue on Ubuntu 16 and 20. This issue also causes my shell script to give the wrong date, so it's not just the cron scheduler.

```
root@ubuntugc:/home/miuser# date -d "20210930+1 month" +%Y-%m-%d
2021-10-30
root@ubuntugc:/home/miuser# date -d "20211030+1 month" +%Y-%m-%d
2021-11-30
root@ubuntugc:/home/miuser# date -d "20211031+1 month" +%Y-%m-%d
2021-12-01
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how `date` works, when adding `1 month` it just increases month by one, in your case to `2021-11-31` which is a date that doesn't exist so it then moves the result one day forward to a valid date (`2021-12-01`). From [coreutils documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html):

> The fuzz in units can cause problems with relative items. For example, ‘2020-07-31 -1 month’ might evaluate to 2020-07-01, because 2020-06-31 is an invalid date. To determine the previous month more reliably, you can ask for the month before the 15th of the current month. For example: